# Gradient text with backgroud-clip: text property breaking up on Mac Safari

Tags: css, macos, safari, cross-browser, word-break

Gradient text with background-clip property is messed up in Mac Safari like this http://prntscr.com/mgd5tz. Here is my code for Gradient text in the span

```css
.text-grad {
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(150deg, #97c74e 0%, #2ab9a5 100%);
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%, #97c74e), color-stop(100%, #2ab9a5));
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(150deg, #97c74e 0%, #2ab9a5 100%);
 background: -o-linear-gradient(150deg, #97c74e 0%, #2ab9a5 100%);
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(150deg, #97c74e 0%, #2ab9a5 100%);
 background: linear-gradient(150deg, #97c74e 0%, #2ab9a5 100%);
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='$color-one', endColorstr='$color-two',GradientType=1 );
 -webkit-background-clip: text;
 -moz-background-clip: text;
 -ms-background-clip: text;
 -o-background-clip: text;
 background-clip: text;
 -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
 -moz-text-fill-color: transparent;
 -ms-text-fill-color: transparent;
 -o-text-fill-color: transparent;
 text-fill-color: transparent;
 opacity: 1;
 z-index: 9;
}
```

```html
<h2>Lorem ipsum <span class="text-grad"> deep understanding </span> of the project</h2>
```

Comment: its working fine for me. i checked it in safari

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding display: inline-block; might work

```css
.text-grad {
  display: inline-block;
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(150deg, #97c74e 0%, #2ab9a5 100%);
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%, #97c74e), color-stop(100%, #2ab9a5));
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(150deg, #97c74e 0%, #2ab9a5 100%);
 background: -o-linear-gradient(150deg, #97c74e 0%, #2ab9a5 100%);
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(150deg, #97c74e 0%, #2ab9a5 100%);
 background: linear-gradient(150deg, #97c74e 0%, #2ab9a5 100%);
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='$color-one', endColorstr='$color-two',GradientType=1 );
 -webkit-background-clip: text;
 -moz-background-clip: text;
 -ms-background-clip: text;
 -o-background-clip: text;
 background-clip: text;
 -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
 -moz-text-fill-color: transparent;
 -ms-text-fill-color: transparent;
 -o-text-fill-color: transparent;
 text-fill-color: transparent;
 opacity: 1;
 z-index: 9;
}
```

```html
   <h2>Lorem ipsum <span class="text-grad"> deep</span> <span class="text-grad">understanding </span> of the project</h2>
```

Comment: Display: inline-block is working fine but It is breaking the text in paragraph

Like this https://prnt.sc/mgrazb

Any help is much appreciated
Thanks for your help!

Comment: I changed the code, now it is working properly, if you put every word that need to get a gradient in a different span it will work :)

Answer (score 0):

this happens because background clip will only work for the inline-block elements. It'll work with span but not with any other block tag. eg. div or headings